# DateTime import using Pandas/SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm having problems importing datetimes from a SQL Server database into Pandas.

I'm using the following code:

```
data = pd.read_sql('select top 10 timestamp from mytable',db)
```

'MyTable' contains a column 'Timestamp', which is of type DateTime2.

If `db` is a pyodbc database connection this works fine, and my timestamps are returned as data type 'datetime64[ns]'.  However if `db` an SQL Alchemy engine created using `create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://...')` then the timestamps returned in `data` are of type 'object' and cause problems later on in my code.

Any idea why this happens?  I'm using pandas version 0.14.1, pyodbc version 3.0.7 and SQL alchemy version 0.9.4.  How best can I force the data into datetime64[ns]?

Comment: To force it, you can use the `parse_dates` keyword of `read_sql` (see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html). But this shouldn't actually be necessary and seems like a bug to me (in pandas or sqlalchemy), can you report it on https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues?

Comment: Done: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8156

Comment: you can accept your own answer, as you did find it out yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the problem originates from how SQL Alchemy calls PyODBC.  By default it will use the 'SQL Server' driver, which doesn't support DateTime2.  When I was using PyODBC directly, I was using the 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0' driver.

To get the correct behaviour, i.e. return python datetime objects, I needed to create the SQL Alchemy engine as follows:

```
import sqlalchemy as sql
connectionString = 'mssql+pyodbc://username:password@my_server/my_database_name?driver=SQL Server Native Client 10.0'
engine = sql.create_engine(connectionString)
```

The `?driver=...` part forces SQL Alchemy to use the right driver.

Comment: The native client is now [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)