# SQLAlchemy and SQL Server Datetime field overflow

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to connect to a SQL Server database.

I'm trying to insert an object into a table from my python script and it's failing.  I'm receiving the error:

```
(pyodbc.DataError) ('22008', '[22008] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Datetime field overflow (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

It looks like this is being caused by the following datetime object:

```
datetime.datetime(214, 7, 21, 0, 0)
```

... that's the 21st July 214

The corresponding date time field in the SQL Server table is of type datetime2.

It looks like the conversion from python/SQLAlchemy to SQL Server isn't adding a '0' to beginning of the year value. I've confirmed this by the fact that I can manually add this date to the SQL Server using an INSERT statement with and without the leading '0'.

Is there a way to force the year part of the date into the correct format? Or is this being caused by something else?

**UPDATE:**
 From https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html I've found that you can specify the type of a column as DATETIME2 (for MS SQL) and I've updated the object mapping accordingly.

So before it was:

```
from base import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Numeric, DateTime

class Results(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Result'

    dateTimeMinValue = Column(DateTime)
    dateTimeMaxValue = Column(DateTime)
```

And I've now updated it to:

```
from base import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Numeric
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import DATETIME2

class Results(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Result'

    dateTimeMinValue = Column(DATETIME2)
    dateTimeMaxValue = Column(DATETIME2)
```

But I still get the same error as before.

Comment: There is at least one more report of problems with ODBC handling of date/time types here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/281326/systemdataodbc-support-of-sql-server-datetime2-tim.html

Comment: So is what I'm trying to do not possible?

Comment: I can't say for sure. Do you have control over the SQL database? Then one could be imaginative about options to work around the issue.

Comment: Yes, I have control over the SQL database.

Comment: Have you changed to the native SQL server client as suggested by Alexander Volok? I believe that that may actually solve the problem.

Comment: Yep, I've changed it and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The corresponding date time field in the SQL Server table is of type
>   datetime2.

Can it be that SQL Alchemy still builds that value as type DATETIME without taking into account corresponding type in a destination table?

[datetime T-SQL:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> **Date range:**   January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999:

Another reason, and seems it is root of the issue, is related to ODBC and DATETIME2:
[error 22008: Datetime field overflow when inserting a record with datetime2 field via ODBC](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ac1b5a6d-5e64-4603-9c92-b75ba4e51bf2/error-22008-datetime-field-overflow-when-inserting-a-record-with-datetime2-field-via-odbc?forum=sqldataaccess)

> Earlier ODBC drivers for SQL Server could infer the server type
>   (datetime or smalldatetime) from the scale (which had to be 0 or 3)
>   and so could be more relaxed than SQL Server 2008 Native Client. The
>   default scale for OdbcParameter is 0, and so earlier drivers could
>   assume the server type must be smalldatetime and ignore any fractional
>   seconds. **With the introduction of datetime2 and a user defined scale
>   of between 0 and 7 the driver can no longer infer the type from the
>   scale and has to default to the richest type, datetime2. When the
>   actual server type is not datetime2 there will be a server side
>   conversion from datetime2 to the actual server type**. I apologise for
>   the invonvenience this has caused you, but we had little choice and
>   the new behavior is documented.

So seems like ODBC, starting with a release SQL Server 2008,  internally change a scale of DATETIME2.

I suggest to follow advice from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607775/datetime-import-using-pandas-sqlalchemy) and switch from ODBC to a native SQL Server Client:

```
import sqlalchemy as sql
connectionString = 'mssql+pyodbc://username:password@my_server/my_database_name?driver=SQL Server Native Client 10.0'
engine = sql.create_engine(connectionString)
```

Comment: I'm using datetime2 in the db, so it should be able to record the year of 214. Yes, it looks like an error (and probably is) but I still need to be able to insert into the db. My problem is the datetime.datetime(214, 7, 21, 0, 0) is generated by sqlalchemy, I'm asking if there is any way to force it to use four digit year values. As I assume this is what the db table needs.

Comment: I suspect that SLQAlchemy just tries to pass a DATETIME value, not a DATETIME2...

Comment: That is probably the case, just need to know how to change it and can't find anywhere on internet that gives any indication that you can.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an ODBC related issue.

Comment: Changing my connection string to connectionString = 'mssql+pyodbc://username:password@my_server/my_database_name?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0' worked (I don't have 10.0 installed, but do ahve 11.0). Thanks for the help. good find.

Comment: To add some more detail, before my connection string was connectionString = 'mssql+pyodbc://username:password@my_server/my_database_name?driver=SQL Server' - adding the the 'Native Client 11.0' was the bit that helped.